# Toggle between two tabs/tables with div display

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net, visual-studio-2012

I want to switch between two tab (lists) in aspx page.

There are two tabs with div tag which start with style="display: block;" and style="display: none;" respectively.

I want to toggle between the two when user clicks on the tab. Here is my code.

```
<ul class="something" role="tablist">
    <li tabindex="0" class="random1" role="tab" aria-selected="true" aria-controls="application-tabs-1" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-1" role="presentation" href="#application-tabs-1">Hello</a></li>
    <li tabindex="-1" class="random2" role="tab" aria-selected="false" aria-controls="application-tabs-2" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2"><a tabindex="-1" class="ui-tabs-anchor" id="ui-id-2" role="presentation" href="#application-tabs-2">World</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="something-else1" id="application-tabs-1" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="true" aria-hidden="false" aria-labelledby="ui-id-1" style="display: block;">
    <table class="applications">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Java</th><th>C</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
    </table>
</div>


<div class="something-else2" id="application-tabs-2" role="tabpanel" aria-expanded="false" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="ui-id-2" style="display: none;">
    <table class="applications">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>English</th><th>French</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

I understand I need to create a jQuery to switch between tables using IDs, and I tried different options but none of them worked.

Option1

```
<script>
   $("#application-tabs-2").show();
   $("#application-tabs-2").hide();
</script>
```

Option 2

```
<script>
   $("#application-tabs-2").css("display", "block");
   $("#application-tabs-2").css("display", "none");
</script>
```

Option 3

```
<script>
   $(document).ready(function displayChange(){
     $("application-tabs-1").toggle();
     $("application-tabs-2").toggle();
   });
</script>
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: are you trying this http://jsfiddle.net/kn816rr1/3/?

Comment: In the first two options, you're setting the same element to show and then instantly hide. In the third option your selector is missing the `#`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to call a function once a tab is clicked. Within the function, find that tab's href to display it, and hide all other siblings (notice I excluded your ul with the class 'something'):

```
$(".ui-tabs-anchor").click(function(event) {
    $("div#"+this.getAttribute('href')).show();
    $("div#"+this.getAttribute('href')).siblings().not('.something').hide();
});
```